# Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=5 "No document at URL" - iCloud / Core Data

Tags: core-data, synchronization, icloud

I'm currently struggling with iCloud integration on Core Data. As far as I can tell all the data is syncing ok but I'm constantly being given errors like the below and wondered if there was something wrong with my setup?

If it helps, this is the store URL prior to addPersistentStoreWithType:

> --- Store URL Before: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/86068CC8-9AF6-45A0-8157-407A52743CC1/Documents/Stores/AppNameicloud.sqlite ---

This is the store URL afterwards:

> --- Store URL After: Optional(file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/86068CC8-9AF6-45A0-8157-407A52743CC1/Documents/Stores/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~69EC9D33-32CE-4747-9C92-FE89F2369F93/AppNameStore999/E9B4AB9A-B977-4E96-AD1E-5345083FED0F/store/AppNameicloud.sqlite))

Here is the error which appears:

> 2016-05-30 18:55:30.686 AppName[1000:311564] __45-[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs]_block_invoke(447): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Librarian returned a serious error for starting downloads Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=5 "No document at URL" UserInfo={NSDescription=No document at URL, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~yourcompany~AppName/AppNameURL999/mobile~69EC9D33-32CE-4747-9C92-FE89F2369F93/AppNameStore999/27MY6G4iIrmUdOAL1QfH7d4IgISU63AZIEyfyZjrCL8=/35D54528-440F-4F48-981E-951A0E8A4C10.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1410fb020 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSDescription=No such file or directory}}} with userInfo {
>       NSDescription = "No document at URL";
>       NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~yourcompany~AppName/AppNameURL999/mobile~69EC9D33-32CE-4747-9C92-FE89F2369F93/AppNameStore999/27MY6G4iIrmUdOAL1QfH7d4IgISU63AZIEyfyZjrCL8=/35D54528-440F-4F48-981E-951A0E8A4C10.1.cdt";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"No such file or directory\" UserInfo={NSDescription=No such file or directory}";
>   } for these urls: {(
>      file:///var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~yourcompany~AppName/AppNameURL999/mobile~69EC9D33-32CE-4747-9C92-FE89F2369F93/AppNameStore999/27MY6G4iIrmUdOAL1QfH7d4IgISU63AZIEyfyZjrCL8=/7F0AFB84-FE8D-4476-99E7-D3F6620625E2.1.cdt
>   )}

I did notice the following in the icloud programming guide for core data:

> **Note**: The store’s final URL may be different from the URL you passed in. If you need a reference to the persistent store, use the URL generated by the coordinator rather than the one you created.

Could this have something to do with the "No such file or directory" Error and should I be checking each time the app loads if there is an iCloud database, then add that instead of passing the Applications Directory version?

As I said, it appears to be working but I'm worried about submitting an update as these Errors look quite bad and do not wish users to lose data.

Thanks

========

After a period of time it definitely gets out of sync and some data stops syncing. I did notice a slightly different Error:

> 2016-05-30 19:53:44.613 AppNameuntil[4570:983927] +PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootLocation:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /Users/Richard/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B6E71CE1-FE9A-47E2-83AE-6440695E5062/data/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~yourcompany~AppNameUntil/AppNameUntilURL999/mobile~55EC7AD8-2DD1-4C57-8977-B3A6101446EE/AppNameUntilStore999/27MY6G4iIrmUdOAL1QfH7d4IgISU63AZIEyfyZjrCL8=/44843227-1C63-44CD-855D-B3BE5B5C0BA7
>   Confused by: 44843227-1C63-44CD-855D-B3BE5B5C0BA7